# App all of a sudden asks “Please run as administrator”, but doing so has no effect

Tags: windows-7, runas

My dad has a Windows 7 system which he primarily uses to play Microsoft Flight Simulator 2004.

His custom setup for this game is huge and there are problems every now an then which can usually be fixed setting configuration files or removing aircraft etc.

But now we are facing a seemingly unsolveable problem. All of a sudden, the game does not start anymore but simple pops up a dialogue saying “please run as administrator.” If I do this, the same dialogue shows up again.

I have tried reinstalling it freshly but the same dialogue pops up again! So the problem must be somewhere inside Windows I guess (we also disabled the anti-virus app and so on).

I have now found “Process Monitor” on the Microsoft website. I have uploaded all entries that [I could filter for one call of `fs9.exe` here](http://www.filedropper.com/fs9prob); the download is a 1.3MB `.pml` file for direct use with “Process Monitor.”

Could someone of you please analyze these entries and tell what is really going wrong on his computer? Or any other suggestions of how to get this running again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has got to do with Microsoft having removed their "Safedisc" service with the most recent Windows Update. Originally meant for Windows 10, this has now been also applied to Win 8 and 7.

In order to reactivate this service, goto command prompt as administrator and type

```
sc config secdrv start= auto
sc start secdrv
```

to start the service permanently again. This will not be possible for Win 10!
So if you have an (old) app that needs this service, do not switch to Win 10.